# Finding Y angle using X, Y & Z

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

I am currently using this code:

```
struct vec3_t
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
};

vec3_t Subtract(vec3_t src, vec3_t dst)
{
    vec3_t diff;
    diff.x = src.x - dst.x;
    diff.y = src.y - dst.y;
    diff.z = src.z - dst.z;
    return diff;
}
float Magnitude(vec3_t vec)
{
    return std::sqrt(vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y + vec.z * vec.z);
}
float Distance(vec3_t src, vec3_t dst)
{
    vec3_t diff = Subtract(src, dst);
    return Magnitude(diff);
}
vec3_t CalcAngle(vec3_t src, vec3_t dst)
{
    vec3_t angles;
    angles.x = (-(float)std::atan2(dst.x - src.x, dst.y - src.y)) / PI * 180.0f + 180.0f;
    angles.y = (std::atan2(dst.z - src.z, Distance(src, dst))) * (180.0f / PI);
    angles.z = 0.0f;

    printf("%f - %f\n", src.z - dst.z, angles.y);


    return angles;
}
```

However my angles are not working fully when the delta of the z value increases.  The angle lacks steepness and aims above the target's position.

However, when the delta of the Z axis is less than 20, the angle works and aims at the player I want it to.

I have some examples here:

**When the delta is really small**

[image: Pic of aiming of bot]

**When the delta is great**

[image: Pic of missing bot]

P.S I am calling it all from the following

```
vec3_t CurrentPos;
CurrentPos.x = x.ReadMemory<float>(LocalPlayer + PlayerOffsetList["PosX"]);
CurrentPos.y = x.ReadMemory<float>(LocalPlayer + PlayerOffsetList["PosY"]);
CurrentPos.z = x.ReadMemory<float>(LocalPlayer + PlayerOffsetList["PosZ"]);

vec3_t EnemyPos;
EnemyPos.x = Enemy.Posx;
EnemyPos.y = Enemy.Posy;
EnemyPos.z = Enemy.Posz;

vec3_t Result;
Result = AimbotMath.CalcAngle(EnemyPos, CurrentPos);

x.WriteMemory<float>(AddrList["ViewX"], (Result.x + 90.0f));
x.WriteMemory<float>(AddrList["ViewY"], Result.y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming, in your `CalcAngles` method that x is yaw and y is pitch:

```
vec3_t CalcAngle(vec3_t src, vec3_t dst)
{
    vec3_t angles;
    vec3_t delta = Subtract(dst, src);
    angles.x = -(float)std::atan2(delta.x, delta.y) / PI * 180.0f + 180.0f;
    //zero out the z to get the *horizontal* distance
    vec3_t horizontal = delta;
    horizontal.z = 0;
    angles.y = std::atan2(delta.z, Magnitude(horizontal)) * (180.0f / PI);
    angles.z = 0.0f;

    printf("%f - %f\n", delta.z, angles.y);


    return angles;
}
```

Note, I left your order of `x` and `y`, along with the offset of `180.0f` because I assume it's correct for your reference point.  Normally `atan2` takes `(y, x)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::atan2(dst.z - src.z, Distance(src, dst))
```

*atan2*  takes the deltas in two axes, typically *x* and in *y*. However, you feed it with the distance on the hypotenuse. The second argument here should be the difference in *y*, probably, not the total distance.

Something like:

```
angles.x = (-(float)std::atan2(dst.x - src.x, dst.y - src.y)) / PI * 180.0f + 180.0f;
angles.y = (-(float)std::atan2(dst.z - src.z, DistanceXY(src, dst)) / PI * 180.0f + 180.0f;
```

I didn't test it, so you may need to adjust the sign up aor down, or rotate 90 or 180 degrees. But the form should be right.

**edit**: In fact, you probably only need to use a 2D distance function that do not use the z component.